# Failed to execute git status ao se atualizar Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, composer, zend-framework-2

Estou dando manutenção em um sistema e, preciso subir algumas alterações para o servidor de produção.
Algumas dessas mudanças envolver mapeamento e adição de novas entidades no banco.

O problema: o arquivo ./vendor/bin/doctrine-module não está no servidor.

O que eu fiz ate agora: subi o meu composer.lock e dei um install.

O seguinte erro acontece ao tentar-se dar update no Doctrine

```
 [RuntimeException]                                             
  Failed to execute git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no  
  error: bad index file sha1 signature                           
  fatal: index file corrupt
```

Já tentei user:

```
rm -f .git/index 
git reset
```

Mas o erro persiste ao rodar o comando novamente.
Algume poderia me ajudar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você removeu o arquivo `.git/index` do projeto principal, provavelmente é o índice de alguma das dependências que está dando problemas.

Exclua a pasta `vendor` e instale as dependências do projeto novamente com `composer install`.